# Link a library using premake

Tags: c++, lib, premake

What is the equivalent syntax to write the below in premake?

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
```

Comment: https://premake.github.io/docs/Linking ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
links
{
    "opengl32.lib",
    "glu32.lib"
}
```

Thank you @dewaffled.